# restart service daily at 4 am

Tags: server, backup, services, reboot

I have a small minecraft server running in ubuntu 22.04.1.

Currently, ubuntu has the following service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Minecraft server
After=network.target

[Service]
User=drgadmin
WorkingDirectory=/home/drgadmin/minecraft-server/
ExecStart=bash ./start-server.bash
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30s
StartLimitInterval=10m
StartLimitBurst=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`./start-server.bash` creates a new backup, then starts the server.

In order to have a daily backup routine, I would like to restart the service daily at 4 am.

Is it possible to configure this daily restart of the service in the service file?
If not, what alternatices can I use?

This is my current `start-server.bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash 
ServerFolder=./paper-1.19.3/

# Current date
now=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")

# Create backup folder if it doesn't exist
if [ ! -d "./backups" ]; then
  mkdir "./backups"
fi

# Create a zip archive of the folder specified in the variable ServerFolder
# the file name is adjusted with the current date
filename="$(basename "$ServerFolder")_$now.tar.gz"
tar cf - "$ServerFolder" | pv | gzip > "./backups/$filename"

# Keep one week of daily backups
# Keep one monthly backup after that time
find "./backups" -type f ! -name "$(basename "$ServerFolder")_*-??-01.tar.gz" -mtime +62 -delete

cd "$ServerFolder"
java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar ./server.jar nogui
```

Comment: the script is used to create a backup of the server before it starts.
Starting the server directly will not create a backup.

Comment: my fundamental problem is not how to stop the server safely. So far, my server gets stopped properly when I request service stop.

My question is: is it possible to configure a service to restart at a given time daily?

Comment: Certainly. You can use cron or systemd timers to do so.

Comment: @julianbechtold see the oncalender event for systemd if you want to do it from within your unit. you can do it from cron but that is the old pre-systemd method ;-)